# Changing Variables in Class from Other Classes (Python)

Tags: python, class, variables

Say I have this code:

```
class hello_world():
    def define_hello(self):
        self.hello = "hello"
    def say_hello(self):
        print self.hello

class change_to_goodbye():
    def __init__(self):
        self.helloWorld = hello_world()
    def hello_to_goodbye(self):
        self.helloWorld.hello = "goodbye"

class other_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.helloWorld = hello_world()
        self.changeToGoodbye = change_to_goodbye()

        self.helloWorld.define_hello()
        self.changeToGoodbye.hello_to_goodbye()
        self.helloWorld.say_hello()

oc = other_class()
```

Class `hello_world` has two methods, one that defines the variable `hello` and one that prints it. On the other hand, class `change_to_goodbye` tries to access the variable `hello` in class `hello_world` and changes it to `goodbye`. Class `other_class` should set the variable `hello` to "hello", change it to "goodbye", and print it on the screen.

I expected the output to be "goodbye" but I got "hello". Why isn't `change_to_goodbye` changing the variable of `hello_world`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `change_to_goodbye` class stores its own `hello_world` object inside it. The `hello_world` object in `changeToGoodbye` is not the same as the hello_world object `helloWorld`. So in `other_class` when you do `self.changeToGoodbye.hello_to_goodbye()`, your helloWorld variable isn't being altered at all. What's being altered is changeToGoodbye's helloWorld object.

So: `self.changeToGoodbye.helloWorld.say_hello()` would return goodbye.

So to summarize:

```
class other_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.helloWorld = hello_world() 
        self.changeToGoodbye = change_to_goodbye() #contains a different hello_world object

        self.helloWorld.define_hello()
        self.changeToGoodbye.hello_to_goodbye() #changes the hello_world object inside of changeToGoodbye
        self.helloWorld.say_hello() #the unaltered helloWorld object
```

if you wanted to change the output of `helloWorld`, you could change the change_to_goodbye class's constructor so that its hello_world object is the one you just created.

```
class change_to_goodbye():
    def __init__(self, hw):
            self.helloWorld = hw

    #other code
```

Comment: Is it possible for `change_to_goodbye` to directly change the variables in class `hello_world` though?

Comment: it does change the variables in hello_world, it's just changing a different instance of hello_world's variables. what you want to do is store the hello_world object you created inside the change_to_goodbye class. this can be done by altering the constructor in the manner I showed at the bottom of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing class variable, you are changing instance variable.

By `self.helloWorld = hello_world()` you defines an `hello_world` instance let's called it **A**, and `self.changeToGoodbye = change_to_goodbye()` you defines an `change_to_goodbye` instance **B** which has an `hello_world` instance **C**.

Then `self.helloWorld.define_hello()` set **A**'s variable as *hello* and `self.changeToGoodbye.hello_to_goodbye()` set **C**'s variable as *goodbye*.

At last `self.helloWorld.say_hello()` will print A's variable, and you will get *hello*.